# How can make scan-build work?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, jenkins, clang, static-analysis

I'm trying to use xcode scan-build tool, but the folder created is deleted with the error:

“scan-build: Removing directory ‘/var/folders/3g/……’ because it contains no reports.”

I want to use this tool since it can create a report that can be read by our CI Server (Jenkins).
I believe that my problem is related to some configuration in my xcode project since with other projects it works and creates the report.

Do you have any clue what may be wrong?

Comment: Hmm, where did you get `scan-build`?  I didn't think it was delivered as part of Xcode?

Comment: Are you using the `--keep-empty` option to scan-build?

Comment: Update: The scan-build works fine with no further configuration needed. My project had no errors and that's why the tool removed the directory. After updating the project, the tool exported a report with data regarding errors. 
Thank you all.